# HAProxy backend - How to connect to remote server?

Tags: haproxy, remote, backend

Good afternoon everyone,

I am a newbie in web hosting and still feel like I am learning to swim in the middle of the ocean. What I want to do is setup HAproxy to forward a request to a remote server in the back end. This server is SSL and behind Cloudflare.

I searched the whole internet but until now I cannot find a straight clear answer to my question. I have pulled haproxy image and I use it in a container with an external haproxy.cfg file. No one clarifies if you are able to use as a server in the backend, a server away from your network (not local) and further more how to use SSL for this communication. If anyone of you have any knowledge about this, I would appreciate an answer if this is doable and how.

I use for now in a server NginxProxyManager container and I am researching the load balancing capabilities of HAProxy. So far I have successfully roundrobin-ed around local containers but with away servers I always get the response in stats "Down for Maintenance". I also have ran in a terminal in the ha-proxy container a wget command and it can see the outside world. If I ping from inside HAProxy container Google, it pings it. All containers are connected both to bridge network and a user created network (bridge driver) in docker. That is why I am completely confused. So, the main question is: can it be done and if it is possible, is the following senario possible (?) :

1. Client makes https request to HAProxy
2. With roundrobin I (would like to) roll between local containers and remote servers
3. When I get to the "remote server" round, I would like to send from the backend the correct server's Host (rewritten - I can do this already but for local containers) along with the information that this is an SSL request.
4. Then NginxProxyManager or another HAProxy would divert it to the connected container there, get the response send it back to the (1st) HAProxy and the latter to the client.

I am not even sure if this is possible. Have a look at the following. It does work with local containers but not with a remote server. It sends the request and rewrites the name of the Host header. Here is the haproxy.cfg

```
global
        maxconn     4000
        daemon

defaults
        mode    http
        default-server init-addr last,libc,none
        option  http-keep-alive
        option  redispatch
        retries 3
        timeout connect 10s
        timeout client  1m
        timeout server  1m
        option forwardfor 


resolvers mynameservers
   nameserver ns2 8.8.8.8:853


frontend stats
        bind *:8500
        stats enable
        stats uri /
        stats refresh 10s


frontend ft
        bind 0.0.0.0:443 ssl crt /usr/local/etc/haproxy/ha_trial.pem  
        default_backend bt2

backend bt2
        balance roundrobin
        http-send-name-header Host        
        server web1 web1:8080 check
        server web2 web2:8080 check
        server web3 web3:8080 check        
        server myback.mysite.com myback.mysite.com:443 ssl verify none resolvers mynameservers
## the latter does not work - it ends at down for maintenance in statistics and in logs it says: Layer6 invalid response, info: "SSL handshake failure" while it is "verify none"
```

If you can help me with an answer if you know it and/or some references all people like me and especially me, would appreciate it highly.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The case is exactly an SSL Handshake Failure case because of HAProxy docker image is not QUIC enabled and the backend is behind Cloudflare which it supports by default QUIC. If I use an other domain that is not QUIC enabled in the communication protocol of https everything works as a charm. I am also curious why on the earth does it handle the frontend and the backend differently??? In front end it understands QUIC (? - or it is QUIC between you and cloudflare and cloudflare to server is different encryption ?) but connecting from the backend is not possible?

So in a nutshell:

1. HAProxy docker image is not QUIC enabled - At least the one I have got (alpine)
2. Cloudflare has activated QUIC by default as a communication protocol for their stuff and you are not allowed to change it.
3. Cooperating of these two is obviously impossible and it throws to your face an "SSL Handshake Failure"
4. In order to fix it use a provider that does support not latest technology communication protocols - ok for now this is mitigation only and no solution.
5. HAProxy site provides a way to recompile HAProxy from github with QUIC support and I will research it later...